# Why I am not getting the output from firebase as string?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app and it uses Firestore, I want to perform queries of my firebase inside it, but my code isn't working (no an error, only not doing its job, nothing), can you help me?. Here is my code in a Flutter:

```
class search extends StatefulWidget {...}
var blank = '';

void _onPressed() async {
  var result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("jobs")
      .where("developer", isEqualTo: "android")
      .getDocuments();
  result.documents.forEach((res) {
    blank = res.data.toString() ;
  });
}



class _searchState extends State<search> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: 
            Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                  child:
                  FlatButton(onPressed: () { _onPressed; },)),
              Text( *blank*)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setState` to rebuild the layout with the new value of `blank`:

```
void _onPressed() async {
  var result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("jobs")
      .where("developer", isEqualTo: "android")
      .getDocuments();
  result.documents.forEach((res) {
    setState(() {
    blank = res.data.toString() ;
   });
  });
}
```